change SOURCE of video?
B"H
Because of how brutal blender's video editing is for large resolutions i started editing a 360p version of my video. Then when I finished, I replaceed the source clips with the original format, 4k. Problem is after i replaced it, it appears clipped off, presumably because blender still thinks that the soruce clip is 360p while it really is 4k now (btw by "replace" I mean I renamed my 4k files to the same name as the 360p versions, copied out the 360p files and in the same folder location I replaced them with the 4k versions).
Any way to fix this? Maybe a script?

I'm not sure about your current issue, but what you are looking for are proxies.

It is hard to suggest something if we dont know how complex your VSE project is. Basically I dont thing there is much to do. Try select all affected strips go to VSE Timeline's side panel (N) > Strip > Transform > Scale X,Y and change it to something that fits your output dimension. It will set scale only to Active strip. Now with a mouse howering above scale values call contextual menu and choose "Copy to Selected". ... For a next time use "proxy" system in blender like suggested by Lutzi.

Fixing the scale
For the scaling issue, it is because Blender automatically fits the video strip to your render resolution when you add a new strip to the timeline, but not when you change that strip's video source.
You can use the menu Image > Apply to either fit, fill or stretch the image to your render resolution:

Using Proxies
As @Lutzi suggested, Blender already have a Proxy system which does essencially what you want: create a low resolution render of your files to let you work on them quickly and keep the original for the final rendering. It's all automated and you don't need to play around making new encodings yourself and swaping files manually. You should definitely use Blender's Proxy system. You can find it in the sidebar > Proxy tab:

Updates not showing up
As for your VSE seemingly not picking up the file update, it could be different things: you could just be looking at an old cache or proxy of the 360p version of your file.
If you enable a few cache options in the View menu, you could see what parts of your timeline are cached:

The caching options can be set in the sidebar > Cache tab, on a global and per-strip basis:

To force refresh the cash, use the menu View > Refresh All or press ⎈ CtrlE.
To go further:
2.1.4. Proxies & cache — Blender VSE Unofficial Documentation documentation

Even your answer is helpful. It does not answering OP's Q. The project is done (so proxy is not an option in this stage of work if is not started from scratch). Refresh cash is also helpfull, but not the problem here. The issue is that placed strips are using some scale (lets say 1). Just by renaming hires source keep video at scale 1. It means 4K video is now in VSE at dimension 10x bigger than 360px lowres.

True, I forgot about that x) editing the answer
